# React Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to load video with a queue system using ReactJS for my UI. But when I setState to change the url of the video I get the error "Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request."

Here is my code:

```
class Videoplayer extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            queue: ['fi4s9uwrg9']
        }
    }
    componentWillMount(){
        fetch(/api).then((res)=>{
            res.json().then((data)=>{
                let hashedqueue = [];
                data.forEach((vid)=>hashedqueue.push(vid.hashed_id));
                this.setState({
                    queue: hashedqueue
                })          
            })
        })
    }
    finishedPlaying(){
        let videos = this.state.queue;
        videos.shift();
        this.setState({queue:videos}) //this is the line thats causing the issue
    }

    render(){       
        return(
        <div className="videoplayer">
            <ReactPlayer ref={player => { this.player = player }} onEnded={()=>this.finishedPlaying()} url={'/videosource/'+this.state.queue[0]} playing />
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

By the way the hashedid is essentially the id of the video

Edit: I'm using this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-player for the video player so I can use wistia with react

Answer (score 0):

If you need access to the state to perform a state update, use a callback instead:

```
  finishedPlaying() {
    this.setState(prevState => {
      // make a shallow copy so as not to mutate state
      const videos = [...prevState.queue];
      videos.shift();
      return { queue: videos };
    });
  }
```

Comment: That still gives me the same error but jumps two videos forward in the queue. Perhaps it is because you have two variables, let and const videos.

Comment: Good catch, forgot to delete those lines above the `setState`.

Comment: Hm, now this goes to the second video when the first one ends but then doesn't go to the third (or any after that). It seems the prop onEnd doesn't get called again